# Looping writes to serializer.save() in Django REST framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I have a function in DRF where I want to tell the system to update "everybody", say I want to give everyone that logged in today a free prize and want to persist that list (I get this example is dumb, it just me trying to generalize my use case). It will query to see which users have signed in today and then I want to loop through those users to create a new activity of giving them a prize.

It appears to only be storing the last value in the loop on write.

```
            time_threshold = datetime.now() - timedelta(hours=12)
            signed_in_list = Activity.objects.filter(created__gte=time_threshold, activity="signed in")
            for activity in signed_in_list:
                serializer.save(user=activity.user_id, activity="gets free prize")
            headers = self.get_success_headers(serializer.data)
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED,
                   headers=headers)
```

I'm trying to get it so that each user ID that is returned from the "signed_in_list" would have a new activity written.

I was expecting a new Activity entry to be written for each user_id in the loop, but it only is executing the last user_id in the loop. That makes me think the serializer.save is working, but overriding itself each time in the loop (versus performing the write to the DB).

Answer (score 0):

You refer to "for user in" and "user.id" when in fact it's not a user, those objects you are referring to are activities.

Ideally I'd like to see your serializer, but given you have passed the same argument as the queryset command I assume the Serializer's model is Activity?

In which case you are attempting to save a new activity with the same primary key id as a previous existing activity which was returned in your queryset. This is an update, but to run an update on a serializer, the Activity instance would need to be passed to the serializer when it was initialized. In general, whether with Django models or DRF serializers, you never need to pass the id to save, especially not an existing id.

Assuming you have a foreign key on the activity model called "user" which references the User model you can do:

`time_threshold = datetime.now() - timedelta(hours=12)
            signed_in_list = Activity.objects.filter(created__gte=time_threshold, activity="signed in")
            for activity in signed_in_list:
                serializer.save(user=activity.user, activity="gets free prize")
            headers = self.get_success_headers(serializer.data)
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED,
                   headers=headers)`

Regarding "user=activity.user", passed as a keyword argument to serializer.save(), this is the way you would do it when saving a model. I think it's the same with DRF serializers, I'm not 100% sure but if it doesn't work you can try user=activity.user.id

Comment: thanks for the comment, I think it got jumbled when I tried to make it more generic for the question. I've corrected it to match the logic in the code that is what you pointed out. It just appears like serializer.save only execute as the end of the create function versus executing each time within this loop

Comment: In your example above, it still only execute a DB write for the last item in the list.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this. Rather than serializer.save, I updated the request and recursively called my create function

```
 def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        time_threshold = datetime.now() - timedelta(hours=12)
        signed_in_list = Activity.objects.filter(created__gte=time_threshold, activity="signed in")
        for activity in signed_in_list:
            request.data["user"] = activity.user
            self.create(request, *args, **kwargs)   
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
```